# Why we use has been in present perfect

Tags: grammar, tense, verbs, present-perfect

It has been a nice trip - present perfect
It was a nice trip -past

How the first sentence could be present perfect because present perfect indicates something that has done recently then why we use such sentences like this. could not we used was instead off has been??
I wanna know the exact meaning with grammers

Another one
I have been part of it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Comment: I don't have problem with perfect i juat wanna know can we use i was part of it instead of i hve been part of it

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of perspective.  When you use *was*, you're looking back on the trip.  When you use *has been*, you're looking at the trip from the present.

Suppose you're talking to someone about a trip you took to Europe last year.  You'd say:

> It was a nice trip.

Now suppose it's the last day of your trip to Europe, and you're talking to your travel partner:

> It's been a nice trip.

You use **has been** because you're still on the trip.

You'd use **was** if the trip is over.